# Create Pandas DatetimeIndex from origin and offsets

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert a set of seconds into a Pandas index suitable for a dataframe.

I think I'm looking for the inverse of the `dt.total_seconds()` operation as in the https://stackoverflow.com/a/36156620/1653571 answer to  [Accessing total_seconds() in pandas data column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36156582/accessing-total-seconds-in-pandas-data-column)

Given:

```
t0="2010-10-01 00:00:00 UTC"
seconds = [0,1,2,3,5,7,11,13]
```

I want something like:

```
ii = pd.DatetimeIndex( ???(t0,seconds))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the `seconds` list to `Timedelta` and do a little `datetime` arithmetic.

```
# origin           + offset
pd.to_datetime(t0) + pd.to_timedelta(seconds, unit='s')
```

```
DatetimeIndex(['2010-10-01 00:00:00+00:00', '2010-10-01 00:00:01+00:00',
               '2010-10-01 00:00:02+00:00', '2010-10-01 00:00:03+00:00',
               '2010-10-01 00:00:05+00:00', '2010-10-01 00:00:07+00:00',
               '2010-10-01 00:00:11+00:00', '2010-10-01 00:00:13+00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', freq=None)
```